# WinForms and C#: How to disable buttons in a groupbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, groupbox

My goal is to disable all buttons (1 and 2) in groupbox1 (see the picture at the end). When I call the following Method DisableAllButtons(), only button 3 is disabled. What am i doing wrong?

```
    private void DisableAllButtons()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (Control c in Controls)
            {
                Button button = (Button)c;
                button.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

[image: Example WinForm]

Comment: `foreach (Control c in groupBox1.Controls)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using the `Controls` on your loop. So you are calling all the controls that is on your form which is the `Button3`and not the controls inside your GroupBox.

To do that, you can do this.

```
public void DisableButton()
{
        List<Button> btn = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
        foreach (var b in btn)
        {
            b.Enabled = false;
        }
}
```